# setIcon,setVisible,setPosition is not working in google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm passing the locations from php to javascript, while i using marker.setIcon, marker.setVisible it's not working. here i give the sample code.

```
<?php
$location = '';
    $location .= '[';
    $counting = count($map_data);   
    // die;
    foreach($map_data as $key=>$feed){      
        if($key>0){
            $location .= ',';   
        }       

        $location .= "['".$feed['Attraction']['location']."', '".$feed['Attraction']['id']."']";
    }
    $location .= ']';
?>
```

if i create the array and use json_encode it shows the missing; after prperty id. so only i used this method. the set icon is worked while mouse over the marker. the seticon is not working while trigger the event. and the js is below

```
var marker, i;
var markers = new Array();
var locations = "<?php echo $location; ?>";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function initialize(locations){
        var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(-12.449380,-50.339844);     
        var zoom_level = 4;

    var mapOpt = { 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: pointA,
        zoom: zoom_level,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        panControl:false,
        scrollwheel: true,
        styles: [
        {
           "featureType": "landscape.natural",
           "elementType": "geometry.fill",
           "stylers": [
           { "color": "#ffffff" }
            ]
        },
        {
           "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
           "stylers": [
           { "color": "#ffffff" },
           { "visibility": "off" }
           ]
        },
        {
           "featureType": "water",
           "stylers": [
           { "color": "#80C8E5" },  // applying map water color
           { "saturation": 0 }
           ]
        },
        {
           "featureType": "road.arterial",
           "elementType": "geometry",
           "stylers": [
           { "color": "#999999" }
            ]
        }
        ,{
           "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
           "stylers": [
           { "visibility": "off" }
          ]
        }
        ,{
           "elementType": "labels.text",
           "stylers": [
           { "color": "#333333" }
           ]
        }
        ,{
           "featureType": "poi",
           "stylers": [
           { "visibility": "off" }
           ]
        }
        ]
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOpt);

    for(var i=0;i<locations.length;i++){        
        (function(address,attr_id) {
            geocoder.geocode({
               'address': address
            }, function(results) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: map,
                   position: results[0].geometry.location,
                   icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"
                });

                    markers.push(marker);   

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                        marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png");
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                        marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png");
                    });

            });
        })(locations[i][0],locations[i][1]);
    }
}
function mouseover_event(index){
    markers[index].setVisible(false);
    map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());    
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[index], 'mouseover');
}
function mouseout_event(index){ 
    markers[index].setVisible(true);
    map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[index], 'mouseout');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Please help  to solve this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Instead of  `var markers = new Array();` i used `var markers = {};` and while pushing the marker i use `markers[i] = marker;` instead of  `markers.push(marker);`

Thanks